# Closing question too biased?

Tags: discussion

[Why would App X need permission Y?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/242690/why-would-app-x-need-permission-y)
was closed as opinion-based, but it is definitely not. Closing the question prevents the community from exchanging *knowledge*.

**Questions**:

Are decision-makers appraisal sometimes too biased?

Is this one such case?

**TL;DR**

The question is completely **technical**, with very specific, non-opinion-based, possible answers. There might be more than one answer for this question, as [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217765/81584) or [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/96209/how-can-i-root-the-micromax-a110q/109337#109337).
Those who could **know** an answer include:

1. Developers or others somehow connected to (now or in the past) apps referred to. E.g., [Query: Sound Meter](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=sound%20meter), [Query: Noise Meter](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=noise%20meter), etc.
2. Developers or others somehow connected to (now or in the past) related open source projects. E.g. [OpeNoise](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.piemonte.arpa.openoise)?, [AudioMeter](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.quaap.audiometer/), [Sound-Meter](https://github.com/jeff2900/Sound-Meter), [Open Sound Meter](https://opensoundmeter.com/), [Sound Recorder](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/54720/why-does-sound-recorder-in-cyanogenmod-need-network-permission).
   These are examples of people who may know the rationale for what I am asking, by being related to the topic at hand (even if not Android app devs themselves at this time).

One could argue about the **chances** that those who know an answer would show up here and post an answer, but that by no means make this opinion-based.
The only way to know this is leaving the question open. It might not get answers... same as [these 14330 questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A0).

Those who don't **know** an answer may **guess**, **recall**, **have seen at one point**, **suggest**, etc., etc... so what could be tagged as opinion-based are the possible answers (and comments).
And these may be **useful** as well. This evaluation is opinion-based (the core of the voting system!!).
Examples: [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/98278/81584), [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/226552/unlocked-samsung-galaxy-s20-ultras-hotspot-is-only-limited-to-1-connection#comment295870_226552), [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/189406/galaxy-s5-charging-slowly-despite-ac-and-2a-charger/189428#189428).

In addition, people not knowing the answer, may have ideas about alternative/better ways to get to an answer, and that is also an answer on its own.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to the meta. As the sole-closer of the question, since I have a conflict of interest, I will defer the discussion to the co-mods and community first before I provide my reasoning.

Comment: @AndrewT. - Quite fair.